# F# interactive does not interact with inputs

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on visual studio 2017 to open F#interactive. But it doesn't interact. For example, when I typed

```
2+2;;
```

Nothing happens. I thought it would print 
`val it : int = 4` . But nothing gets printed. Maybe I got an error before that line and that made it not working properly? But when I close the F# interactive window using the x sign on the top right of the window and reopen it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, I don't get a new window, instead I get the Window as it were when I closed it. So how should I make this work properly? Is this the right way to open F# interactive on visual studio? Here is a image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that F# Interactive is stuck somehow.

You can reset F# Interactive in Visual Studio by right clicking in the F# Interactive window and select "Reset Interactive Session" from the drop down menu.